# How to make focused EditText visible while soft keyboard pops up?

Tags: java, android, uiview, android-manifest, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to make an application where content inside a Layout is dense. However I want functionality which will keep showing my focused EditText on top half of the screen while soft keyboard pops up...

So far my research says I have to use...

```
   <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified" android:name=".main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.last.project.main" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I have been told that (this) android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified" line of Manifest.xml  will solve my problem, However it doesn't seems to be working.
(I have been told means .... from this link I read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft )

Just need to know why it is not working...Are there any other reasons which may affect my manifest XML to just ignore what I have wrote?

Do let me know if any other codes needed

Thanks heaps,

Krio

My layout XML is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/header" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:baselineAligned="false" 
    android:layout_gravity="fill">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="English" android:id="@+id/button1" 
            android:onClick="languageSelectionButtonFrom" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="2">
        </Button>
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" 
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        </ImageButton>
        <Button android:text="English" 
            android:onClick="languageSelectionButtonTo" 
            android:id="@+id/button3" 
            android:layout_gravity="right" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="2">
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <EditText android:hint="Text to translate..."  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/editText1" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>
        <Button android:text="Translate" 
            android:id="@+id/button4" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:onClick="translationButtonClickHandler" >
        </Button>
        <TextView android:text="Translation :" 
            android:textSize="15sp" 
            android:id="@+id/textView1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <EditText android:text="" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/editText2" 
            android:scrollbars="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="4" 
            android:gravity="top"  
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </EditText>
     </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem has been solved Thank you for people who have attempted to brain strom...

answer is...We must put all layout content inside a scroll view to get this thing work!

So, In my case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
....(All other content omitted for whole file reference same xml text inside question)
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```